# Power Query to Fetch Data from SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba, t-sql

Hope everything is good from your end..

I am working on projects wherein data is being extracted from SQL and further process (sorting, lookup, validation, cleaning) is accomplished in Excel and now I wanted to create a file wherein data will be fetched from SQL to excel thru power Query and SQL query (MS) inputs will be accessed thru excel cells. So could you please me with this process or suggest any best side to get this information on who this can be done.

I saw it is possible, but tried a lot and it never work.

Comment: `Data` -> `Get Data` -> `From Database` -> `From SQL Server Database`?

Comment: But my challenge how can I pass SQL parameters input thru excel cells... Let's say Select * from mydb where projectid in ()

Comment: Now in the projectid in ().  Parameters I need to pass 50+ projects thru excel cells.. how this can be done in Excel in pq? Pls help